# How to turn off animation when presenting modally via segue

Tags: storyboard, ios9, xcode7, uistoryboardsegue

I would like to present a view controller modally but I don't it to animate on screen. How do I turn off that animation when presenting modally via storyboard segue?

Answer (score 0):

Just select the segue in the storyboard and then uncheck animated.

[image]